# How to replace only once a find string?

Tags: php

For example there is a string :

```
$valeur = "a-b-c-b-d-e";
```

The letter "b" is present twice in this. I want to replace only the first "b".

How to do that ? I used `str_replace` but it replaces all occurences.

Comment: becareful with answers suggesting you to use the fourth parameter of `str_replace` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cab try preg_replace here.

```
    $valeur = "a-b-c-b-d-e";
    echo preg_replace('/b/', 'x', $valeur, 1); // outputs 'a-x-c-b-d-e'
```

Here 4th parameter is for limit and this is optional.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_replace` and set a limit like so:

```
$valeur = "a-b-c-b-d-e";
$replacement = '#';

echo preg_replace('/b/', $replacement, $valeur, 1); // a-#-c-b-d-e
```

You didn't mention what you wanted to replace it with so I'm adding `#` as a placeholder.

Comment: @wallyk that's the fifth parameter you are talking about http://sg2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @NiftyDude:  Yep, thanks.  Comment deleted as I have now read the docs.